Update ActiveFlag in AccountUser With SSJS POST SOAP Request Returns Status 200 but Data Not Updated
(translate with chatgpt from Chinese)
Hello, I developed a functionality where I used WSProxy to retrieve the required AccountUser, then obtained an access token and sent a SOAP request to update the ActiveFlag to false.
The response returned a status 200, but when checking the user in the setup, I didn't see any updates. Could anyone help me understand what might be the reason?
  function inactiveUser(){
var OverdueLoginUsers = findOverdueLoginUsers();
var accessToken = getAccessToken();
var updateURL = 'https://' + domain + '.soap.marketingcloudapis.com/Service.asmx';
var ContentType = 'text/xml';

var payloadToUpdate = '';
payloadToUpdate +=  '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';
payloadToUpdate +=  '<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">';
payloadToUpdate +=      '<s:Header>';
payloadToUpdate +=          '<a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">update</a:Action>';
payloadToUpdate +=          '<a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">https://' + domain + '.soap.marketingcloudapis.com/Service.asmx</a:To>';
payloadToUpdate +=          '<fueloauth xmlns="http://exacttarget.com">' + accessToken + '</fueloauth>';
payloadToUpdate +=      '</s:Header>';
payloadToUpdate +=      '<s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">';
payloadToUpdate +=          '<CreateRequest xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">';
payloadToUpdate +=              '<Objects xsi:type="AccountUser">';
payloadToUpdate +=                  '<PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"></PartnerKey>';
payloadToUpdate +=                  '<ObjectID xsi:nil="true"></ObjectID>';
payloadToUpdate +=                  '<Client>';
payloadToUpdate +=                      '<ID>' + OverdueLoginUsers[1].ClientId + '</ID>'; // Paste MID
payloadToUpdate +=                  '</Client>';
payloadToUpdate +=                  '<AccountUserID>' + OverdueLoginUsers[1].AccountUserID + '</AccountUserID>'; // Paste UserID
payloadToUpdate +=                  '<ActiveFlag>false</ActiveFlag>';
payloadToUpdate +=              '</Objects>';
payloadToUpdate +=          '</CreateRequest>';
payloadToUpdate +=      '</s:Body>';
payloadToUpdate +=  '</s:Envelope>';


try{
  var headerNames = ["SOAPAction", "Authorization"];
  var headerValues = ["Update", "Bearer " + accessToken]; // Authorization 以 "Bearer " 開頭

  var HttpPost = HTTP.Post(updateURL, ContentType, payloadToUpdate, headerNames, headerValues);
  if (HttpPost.StatusCode == 200) {
    Write("SOAP request was successful.<br>");
    Write("SOAP request respone: " + HttpPost.Response + "<br>");
  } else {
    Write("SOAP request was failed, StatusCode: " + HttpPost.StatusCode + "<br>");
    Write("SOAP request respone: " + HttpPost.Response + "<br>");
  }
}catch(error){
  Write('update error: ' + error.message + '<br>');
  Write('update error full message: ' + Stringify(error) + "<br>");
}
}

OverdueLoginUsers[1] is confirmed to have data, and after a successful request, it is expected to be changed to all OverdueLoginUsers.

This is how I would do it using SSJS, to deActivate list of users from A Data Extension. [which is preprocessed using SQL/other scripts]
<script runat="server">
Platform.Load("Core","1.1.1");


/* Update BU realted API details */
var VCV_client_id = "xxx";
var VCV_client_secret = "xxx";
var VCV_account_id = "536001234";
var VCV_subdomain = "xxx";

/* Preparing Payload */
var payload =   {   client_id: VCV_client_id,
                    client_secret: VCV_client_secret,
                    grant_type: "client_credentials",
                    account_id: VCV_account_id
                };
var url = 'https://'+ VCV_subdomain +'.auth.marketingcloudapis.com/v2/token';
var contentType = 'application/json';

try {   
        /* STEP-01:: Generating access token */
        var accessTokenRequest = HTTP.Post(url, contentType, Stringify(payload));
        if(accessTokenRequest.StatusCode == 200) 
        {
            var tokenResponse = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(accessTokenRequest.Response[0]);
            var accessToken = tokenResponse.access_token;
            var BearerT = 'Bearer ' + accessToken;
        }
              // Write("access token = " + BearerT);


        /* STEP-02 :: SOAP call to update AccountUser object */
          //var AccountUserID = "sfmc.ninja@yopmail.com";
          var URL = 'https://' + VCV_subdomain + '.soap.marketingcloudapis.com/Service.asmx';
          var ContentType = 'text/xml';
          var DE = "InactiveUsersDE"; //DE where users to be Inactivated
          var InactiveUsersDE = DataExtension.Init(DE);
          var InactiveUsersDERows = InactiveUsersDE.Rows.Retrieve();
          

          /* Looping through all users to disable from DE */
          if (InactiveUsersDERows.length > 0) 
          {
            for(var i in InactiveUsersDERows) 
              {
                var AccountUserID = InactiveUsersDERows[i]["UserID"];
                var Payload = '';
                Payload +=  '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';
                Payload +=  '<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:u="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">';
                Payload +=      '<s:Header>';
                Payload +=          '<a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">Create</a:Action>';
                Payload +=          '<a:To s:mustUnderstand="1">https://' + VCV_subdomain + '.soap.marketingcloudapis.com/Service.asmx</a:To>';
                Payload +=          '<fueloauth xmlns="http://exacttarget.com">' + accessToken + '</fueloauth>';
                Payload +=      '</s:Header>';
                Payload +=      '<s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">';
                Payload +=          '<CreateRequest xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">';
                Payload +=              '<Options>';
                Payload +=                  '<SaveOptions>';
                Payload +=                      '<SaveOption>';
                Payload +=                          '<PropertyName>*</PropertyName>';
                Payload +=                          '<SaveAction>UpdateAdd</SaveAction>';
                Payload +=                      '</SaveOption>';
                Payload +=                  '</SaveOptions>';
                Payload +=              '</Options> ';
                Payload +=              '<Objects xsi:type="AccountUser">';
                Payload +=                  '<PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"></PartnerKey>';
                Payload +=                  '<ObjectID xsi:nil="true"></ObjectID>';
                Payload +=                  '<Client>';
                Payload +=                      '<ID>' + VCV_account_id + '</ID>'; // Paste MID
                Payload +=                  '</Client>';
                Payload +=                  '<UserID>' + AccountUserID + '</UserID>'; // Paste AccountUserID
                Payload +=                  '<ActiveFlag>false</ActiveFlag>';
                Payload +=              '</Objects>';
                Payload +=          '</CreateRequest>';
                Payload +=      '</s:Body>';
                Payload +=  '</s:Envelope>';

                var HttpPost = HTTP.Post(URL, ContentType, Payload);
              // Write("Updated = "+ AccountUserID + "<br>");
              }
          }



    }//try

    catch (error) 
    {
        Write("access token = " + BearerT);
        Write("Inside ERROR test <br/><br/>");
        Write(Stringify(error));
    }
</script>


I extend my deepest gratitude; the approach you provided helped me straighten out my faulty code.
